# Need help understanding steps and correct mistakes in a beginner level integral problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm working on the following integration problem: $\int^4_1\frac{2+x^2}{\sqrt{x}}$

My answer:
$$\int^4_1(2+x^2)\cdot x^{-1/2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\int^4_1(2x^{-1/2}+x^{3/2})$$
$$\Rightarrow\left[-4x^{1/2}+\frac{2}{5}x^{5/2}\right]^4_1$$
$$\approx 12.026$$

Microsoft Math Solver's answer: [answer by math solver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhPRF.jpg)

My Approach:

- I inverted the denominator and distributed it.
- I integrated.

Areas of confusion:

- I'd like to understand the reasoning behind the integration step in Math solver's solution.

Request:

Could someone please help me:

- Identify the mistakes in my approach or calculations.
- Explain the correct steps and reasoning behind the math solver's solution.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations instead of images

Comment: Please avoid relying on online mathematical solvers, or use trusted ones like WolframAlpha. Very often they aren't right.

Comment: @NoChance: It's not Math Solver's that's to blame... See the answer that I posted below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out guys, I took into account all of your suggestions and comments.

Comment: @Sgg8 do you recommend any video tutorial for MathJax?.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark yes this helped me figure it out.

Comment: @HansLundmark, thanks for clearing this issue.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanYehia, what you would need to type expressions here is usually very little of MathJax/LaTex. You could learn by seeing some examples in addition to the basics like: (1) put your expression between Dollar signs. (2) use curly braces instead of regular braces for arguments.(3) use ^ for exponents. (4) use braces sparingly. 
(5) use "\frac{a/b}" to represent fractions like a/b. See the drop down Latex Examples in https://arachnoid.com/latex/ . As you select an expression from the drop-down, the corresponding code will be displayed (without dollar signs).

Comment: @AbdelrahmanYehia you won't need any video tutorial. Most of what you'll need is basics listed by NoChance above. When you need something else, just follow the link to the SE tutorial I gave you and search what you need by "Ctrl+F"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you the answer, but still edit your question. The Math solver is wrong. And your answer is also wrong because
$$\int 2x^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}} x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 4 \sqrt{x} + C \neq - 4 \sqrt{x} + C$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment, because of the URLs...)

That's not Math Solver's output! Surely not even Microsoft would get it *that* outrageously wrong.

Actually Math Solver computes [the correct antiderivative](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60displaystyle%60int%7B%20%20%60frac%7B%20%20%60left(%202%2B%20%7B%20x%20%20%7D%5E%7B%202%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%60right)%20%20%20%20%7D%7B%20%20%60sqrt%7B%20x%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7Dd%20x) and [the correct definite integral](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60displaystyle%60int_%7B%201%20%20%7D%5E%7B%204%20%20%7D%20%20%60frac%7B%20%20%60left(%202%2B%20%7B%20x%20%20%7D%5E%7B%202%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%60right)%20%20%20%20%7D%7B%20%20%60sqrt%7B%20x%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20d%20x) too. But what it also does is to find, and link to, [another math.SE question about the same integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750972/two-values-for-int-14-frac2x2-sqrtx-dx), which contains exactly the nonsensical formulas in your screenshot, so I suppose you got there by clicking on that link. But don't blame that on Math Solver...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, the math solver showed me the right answer, and these steps below it, I thought these were the steps for that answer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: do you recommend any completely free step by step math solver.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any such thing.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks anyways!